# How to load drivers in C# .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, kernel, driver

Hello I'm trying to find a method that can load (kernel) drivers.
I've searched a bit for it but didn't found any method to do that, so is that even possible or not because I dont want to just throw away my entire C# project I built long time.

Hope I get some answers.

What did you try: I tried finding a method for loading that, and tried to write my own code.
What do you expect to happen: Hopefully a solution

Comment: What are you trying to do? .NET code is user mode-only, with no access to the Kernel except via the start. NET (and eventually OS) APIs.

Comment: so i cannot load kernel drivers with c# right?

Comment: Kernel Drivers are called Kernel Drivers because they are run (are loaded) by the kernel. And they access things only accessible inside the kernel. Even if you find ways to load it into your application it can't do anything it was designed for. What are you trying to achive with loading a driver?

Comment: im trying to make a sp00fer for myself

Comment: Then you need to write a kernel driver with an api(written in c loaded into the kernel) that can be called from a net app (written in c# running in standard user space). An example for that would be Npcap and the PCAP Net Wrapper that allows capturing Low Level Network traffic.

Comment: I have no idea about it, I've only just managed to code the driver and build it, so a sys file. Could you perhaps explain it a little more simply or more step by step so that I can follow along? Would be nice.

Comment: I hope you are ready.to blue screen your box often. Writing kernel drivers is an exacting art. It's real easy to write a bad one and very hard to write a good one. Also, except for some test setups, Windows won't load your driver unless it's WHQL signed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/whql-test-signature-program

Comment: I know that, but my kernel driver code is finished and it seems to work but like I said, the only problem I have is to load the driver and communicate between the driver and the program, that should execute the driver. I've written a Test Driver and a c++ program that can load and test that driver but I still dont found any way to communicate or like that prints that are in the driver are getting printed in the c++ program.

Comment: Any answer?????